# conversion of document text to speech

Tags: android

i followed the following tutroial for tts

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/09/introduction-to-text-to-speech-in.html

but now how do i make it work for documents
i want to extract the text in documents and convert it to speech
and want the functionality to stop,pause play functions in it as in a media player

By documents,i mean word,pdf etc.please tell how to extract text from these documents in android.i am newbie to android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step #1: "Extract the text in documents". That is up to you, as you are the only person on the planet who knows what "documents" you are referring to.

Step #2: "Convert it to speech" using the text-to-speech engine you linked to above, converting the results into an audio file (see the "File rendering and playback" section).

Step #3: Use `MediaPlayer` to create your own playback activity with "stop,pause play functions" as you see fit.

Comment: by documents,i mean word,pdf etc.please tell me how to extract text from these documents.i am a newbie to android

Comment: @user575805: There is nothing in Android "to extract text from these documents". You are welcome to go hunting for some open source Java library that can do that work for you.